# How to convert a .lvm X-value to unix time stamp

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-16.04, labview, iso8601

I have a set of .lvm files which has a X_values such as:

```
150023,495000
150023,496000
150023,497000
150023,498000
```

Time mentioned in .lvm file is

```
Date    2018/04/30
Time    11:57:52,3446583300349227878
```

And to my understanding X_value represents the time, i want them to be converted into unix time stamp order.

But when i convert them they are giving me very different values, Is there a way to convert so that instead of this values i get unix time stamp or ISO 8601.

```
    from datetime import datetime
    print datetime.fromtimestamp(150023.495000)
```

which gives an output:

```
    1970-01-02 18:40:23.495000
```

It would be great to point out what i am missing while converting this values from .lvm files.

Comment: Can you attach the header of the file? Did you read http://www.ni.com/tutorial/4139/en/

Comment: @TonPlomp hi, i read the description of .lvm file, should i be looking at something specific ?

Comment: I'm not sure without looking at the header. Could you add that?

Comment: i got the solution you are right,everything was within the header. i just added my date and time in header with my X_value to calculate the present time.

Comment: Could you write up your solution as a separate answer?